# How to select all the vertices i can select only the vertices visible in the camera view

Tags: modeling

Hi i am trying o select all the vertices but unable to select all when used drag to select but i can choose all in the wire frame mode  i found  Limit selection to visible can be used to select the vertices without going to wire frame mode but how to enable it .Thanks in Adv.[image]

Comment: You can probably select the rest by hovering over one of the verts and hitting 'L'. Just Box selecting in Solid view will select only the visible vertices as you've found.

Comment: @JohnEason Looks a bit like as if the object was one connected mesh. Hitting `L` will then simply select everything, not just the lower part.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann True. That's why I said "probably". Difficult to say without seeing the Blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable X-Ray mode in order to select occluded areas (Shortcut Alt Z).

[image]