Selection full object in Edit Mode
I am a new user of Blender. I have an issue with selection of an object in edit mode. Is there a way select an object in total, not only the side that is visible in preview but the full object?
Thanks!

Hit A which will select the whole object and follow some beginner tutorials on selection in Blender!!

Thank you so much for help! it worked <3

@JohnEason That appears to be an answer. Please post it as such.

Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308941/how-to-select-all-the-vertices-i-can-select-only-the-vertices-visible-in-the-cam

@TheLabCat  To be honest I don't think that requires an answer as it's a fundamental part of modelling in Blender and is one of the first things one should learn from tutorials.

@JohnEason downvote the question for lack of research if you must, but what you posted is still an answer to the question.

OP do you know about the Blender Manual?
